# Cannot scroll to absolute bottom of the page in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to figure out whats going on in my website that in mobile devices im not able to scroll till the end where the arrow up is.

I need you to help me. Thanks

My website is www.agustinmoles.byethost32.com

**EDIT:** I have found that the error is in some part of this code, but I don't think its bad... hmmmm

```
function deSeccion1A2() {
    deSeccionXaSeccionY('#section1 #portfolio i','#section2');
}

function deSeccion2A3() {
    deSeccionXaSeccionY('#section2 .bottom-arrow','#section3');
}

function deSeccion3AContact() {
    deSeccionXaSeccionY('#section3 .bottom-arrow','#contact-section');
}

function deContactATop() {
    deSeccionXaSeccionY('#contact-section .bottom-arrow','#section1');
}

function deSeccionXaSeccionY (nombreElemento, nombreDivAMoverse) {
    $(nombreElemento).click(function() {
        var altoSection = $(nombreDivAMoverse).offset().top;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: altoSection},700);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript on your page scrolls to each section so it fills the screen. On mobile the screen is not tall enough, so it can't fit the whole section, and because there is no next section it stops the scrolling. A lazy fix would be to disable that functionality on mobile or to adjust the bottom position of `.adios` and `bottom-arrow`.

If you can reproduce the issue on here using a code snippet, you might get some better solutions.

EDIT:

Try changing the font size of the below selector to `font-size:2.8em`. The title seems to be breaking out of the DIV which seems to be causing the issue. I am not 100% sure but this could be causing the `vh` units calculation to be off slightly.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
  #contact-info h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
    width: 97%;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 3.8em;
  }
}
```

Comment: But I think its tall enough because I used 100vh for each section, maybe I can create a div that is only for mobile that put an space after the last section but it would also be a lazy fix.

Comment: I didn't notice you were using 100vh, I'll take another quick look at it.

Comment: If you need a part of the code I can show you. Maybe its a mistake in the media query of the css

Comment: @AgustinMoles I have edited my answer. It seems to fix the issue on my end. In future it is always good to show some sample code.

Comment: It didnt work, the error also happend when the last section was the "showroom". So I think the problem becomes from other source. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I have edited the topic, I found where the problem is coming